# How to select rows according to a regex?

Tags: php, mysql, regex

I have a table like this:

```
// mytable
+----+----------------------+
| id |       sentence       |
+----+----------------------+
| 1  | thIs! is, a** tEst?  |
| 2  | and also This ^ is&  |
| 3  | --it^% is tOo.       |
+----+----------------------+
```

Also I have a variable:

```
$str = "this-is-a-test";
/* the above string is made according to this:
   strtolower(trim(preg_replace('~[^0-9a-z]+~i', '-', $str)));
*/
```

Also here is my query:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE sentence = '$str';
```

Now I want this **output:**

```
+----+----------------------+
| id |       sentence       |
+----+----------------------+
| 1  | thIs! is, a** tEst?  |
+----+----------------------+
```

---

How can I apply that regex on column temporarily before searching?

Comment: `this-is-a-test` is generally not going to be considered a regular expression. Are you asking how to perform a regex selection in general? (If so, Google is your friend... and your query is wrong; search before asking for help). Are you asking for a regular expression that will match your sentence in row 1? If so, you should probably be reading about how to form regular expressions so that you are in position to apply at least minimal effort before asking for help. Do you have an actual regex that is just failing to match this input? If so, you should post it so someone can correct it for you.

Comment: @mah Ok forget that regex .. I have this string: `this-is-a-test`, And I have this field in the database: `thIs! is, a** tEst?`. How can I select that field in the database using that string?

Comment: @stack Via a regex =) See [regexes in mysql](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/regexp.html)

Comment: @stack you cannot. You either need a valid regex that is able to match your string (via SELECT...REGEXP), or you need a valid substring (via SELECT...LIKE, using wildcards), or the full string. Something else is not going to cut it. You might find what you need using `SELECT ... WHERE ... LIKE "%this%is%a%test%"` but while that will match your posted input, it will match many things you probably don't intend (since `%` matches more than just non-letters`

Comment: @mah Well, How can I use this regex `~[^0-9a-z]+~i` to match my string in my query?

Comment: stack did you read the link @syck provided? He did your googling for you... please try to help yourself using some reasonable effort. If after that you are still stuck, you'll have much better results on SO by posting the expression and code/query you're trying and failing with.

Answer (score 0):

You can perform searchs with Regular Expression in MySQL :)
**DO NOT BE CONFUSED !** RegEx Will be performed by SGBD, NOT by PHP !!

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE sentence REGEXP '$str';
```

for more informations, visit MySQL documentations [MySQL REGEXP](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/regexp.html)

Comment: Where is this pattern ? `~[^0-9a-z]+~i`

Comment: @stack a better question, one for you to answer (or get help from your professor / GTA, if you're expected to know the answer already) is _what does this pattern match?_ Based on what you're trying to accomplish, I'm pretty certain it does not do what you want it to do (unless there's a bit of information you have not provided). That pattern, when processed by php (and NOT by MySQL) appears to match a string of non-alpha-numeric characters... which clearly is insufficient for what you're trying to match.